# UIPickerview AppDelegate problem with subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

Issue with subviews but it may be related to the AppDelegate with respect to placing a UIPickerView in myView as apposed to self.view?

Thanks

```
[self.view addSubview:pickerView]; <-- works ok
//[myView addSubview:pickerView];<-- fails, can't get dial movement or response
```

AppDelegate.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class PickerViewController;
@interface PickerViewAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    PickerViewController *pvController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "PickerViewAppDelegate.h"
#import "PickerViewController.h"
@implementation PickerViewAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    pvController = [[PickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickerView"    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [window addSubview:pvController.view];
     // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [pvController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,     UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *arrayColors;
}
@end
```

Controller.m

```
#import "PickerViewController.h"
@implementation PickerViewController
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    arrayColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<60; i++) {
        [arrayColors addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    }
    //[self.view addSubview:pickerView]; // <-- works
    [myView addSubview:pickerView]; // <-- this fails.. this is what I need for multiple views
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [arrayColors release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker View Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [arrayColors count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [arrayColors objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [arrayColors objectAtIndex:row], row);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment

```
    [myView addSubview:pickerView];
```

you will understand, that myView frame is too small. You will be able to interact with the picker only touching that parent view frame. If you want to make the pickers behave normally, you must set the parent view frame to contain the picker frame - make it equal or larger.

Please remember iOs Human Interface Guidelines,

> The overall size of a picker, including its background, is fixed at the same size as the keyboard on iPhone.

Comment: The big thing that I want to do, but it may be violating IOS HIG, is to place 4 UIPickerViews side by side, but resizing them by putting them in UIView. This works doing it from the Interface Builder, but doing it from code, the UIPickerView doesn't change size.  Others must be doing this because I see have seen 4 dials next to each other unless there is a setting in the UIPickerView to do 4 dials ???

Comment: @jdl, use - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView  - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component  to get multiple rows in a single picker.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that myView has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`?

Comment: [myView addSubview:pickerView];
 myView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;  <-- not changing anything